# triangular matrix is invertible counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra

when i was reading the book "elementary linear algebra with applications" by Howard Anton, Chris Rorres. There is a theorem said

**A triangular matrix is invertible iff its diagonal entries are all non zero.**

I know how to proof this theorem, but he immediately shows a counterexample without explaining it.
the counter example is as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}3&-2&2\\0&2&-1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

My question is why this is not invertible, and why this theorem does not hold for this case. Further, is there a strong statement to conclude this theorem. Many thanks.

Comment: If the book really proves a theorem, and then gives a counterexample to it, then I would advise you to throw the book.

Comment: Probably a typo.  The matrix you put in the question is invertible. In the version of Anton and Rorres I just looked at (11th ed), there is almost this example, but with a $0$ (not a $2$) in the row 2, column 2 entry.

Comment: hahah, i dont know if i miss something or what. but this book has a good reputation online, and it indeed explain things well

Comment: thank you so much, then this must be an error in the book!

Comment: Indeed, if it is a typo and the real matrix is as @leslietownes says, then the book is correct. Except for the fact that the matrix is no longer a *counterexample* to the theorem, but just an *example* to it.

Comment: yes, thank you! its not a counterexample, just a "example",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a typo in the $9^{\text{th}}$ edition (and maybe earlier editions) of the textbook. The $10^{\text{th}}$ edition and later editions correctly say:

> Consider the upper triangular matrices $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&-1\\0&2&4\\0&0&5\end{bmatrix}\qquad B = \begin{bmatrix}3&-2&2\\0&0&-1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$*It follows from part (c) of Theorem 1.7.1. that* the matrix $A$ is invertible, since its diagonal entries are nonzero, but the matrix $B$ is not.

Note the $0$ in the center of matrix $B$, corrected from the $2$ in your edition. The text in italics is also added in the $10^{\text{th}}$ edition.

Comment: thank you my friend, i was really thinking whats going on with this one. You guys are awsome, this is my first time post a question, didnt expect reply so fast